# How to determine literal's type in Python?

Tags: python, ruby, types, literals

In Ruby, you can use `.class` to determine the type of literals. For example:

```
   100.class 
=> Fixnum
   "Hi".class
=> String
   3.14.class
=> Float
   [1, 2, 3].class
=> Array
   {:name => "John"}.class
=> Hash
```

How can I do the same thing in Python? I know what is literal and Python literal syntax. I just want to know if there is a way for me to determine it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `type()` what you're looking for...?

Comment: The same way you determine the type of *anything*: you pass it as an argument to `type`.

Comment: Your understanding of Ruby seems to be rather warped. `Object#class` does *not* return the type, it returns the *class*, which is something very different. (Hint: the name of the method kind-of gives this away.) And, it doesn't return the class of the literal, it returns the class of the object *denoted by* the literal. Literals are a purely syntactic construct in Ruby, they don't exist at runtime, they are not objects, and therefore you cannot call methods (like `Object#class`) on them. Oh, and lastly, I could monkey-patch, say, `String#class` to return something different.

Comment: It would be better if you could describe the problem you are facing instead of just asking "how can I achieve what this Ruby code does in Python". For one, this question can only be answered by someone who understands *both* Ruby *and* Python, which is considerably less than the number of people who understand Python, plus, the Ruby code doesn't even do what you claim it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `type`, as answered before - but this feature is for inspection purposes, mainly in repl/shell/console etc.

I mean, writing something like that,

```
if type(a) == int:
    do_something()
```

is not pythonic.

For that kind of purposes, use `isinstance(variable, class_name)` which is more pythonic and much more meaningful. I used meaningful because, as an object based/oriented language, python doesn't have types, at least you should pretend that it does not have types. Every object you've created, or produced as output of procedures you've created are instances of some classes - at least you should approach python that way.

Answer (score 3):

Use `type()`:

```
>>> type(2)
<class 'int'>
>>> type(2.2)
<class 'float'>
>>> type(100)
<class 'int'>
>>> type("hi")
<class 'str'>
>>> type(3.14)
<class 'float'>
>>> type([1,2,3])
<class 'list'>
>>> type({'a': 1})
<class 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `type(expression)` to determine the type of the expression